# How to sum rows based on another row in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

[image: Expected Result]

How can get the result (above) based on another row, Please refer on sample if statement on how i want to get the result.

Sample Table Structure
[image]

PowerBi Matrix sample
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [LOOKUPVALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax)

```
ExpectedResult = IF('Table'[Item]="Soda", 
                    'Table'[Input]+LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Bad],'Table'[Item],"Tea",'Table'[Date],'Table'[Date]),
                    'Table'[Input])
```

Comment: i got error " A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected "

Comment: In that case, you are having multiple rows with `Item = "Tea"`. Which value you want to take if same items are appearing more than once? @JackyMontevirgen

Comment: ahh i see thats why, because i have a table with multiple item = "Tea" per Date, can we used date for reference?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for this case along with expected ouput? @JackyMontevirgen

Comment: Hi i update the question and add some sample table structure and PowerBi matrix expected result.

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen. Just add `Date` Field as another criteria. Updated my answer

Comment: What is the search value for date?

Comment: Here the `search value` is same as current rows `date` value. i.e., `date` of item `tea` @JackyMontevirgen. That is why i have mentioned both `searchcolumn` and `searchvalue` as `date`. This query should work as it is. Did you tried running it?